# Determining whether values held in variables are unique

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I'm trying to 'brute force' a number puzzle, one of the criteria of which is that the calculation uses each of the digits 0-9 once only. I start by extracting the individual digits of each possible answer to a bunch of variables (but changing it to an array would be no great problem), but determining whether they are unique is a melon-scratcher - it looks like potentially a lot of if statement conditions: if a!=b && b!=c && a!=c; this is going to get long winded with 10 variables!

Am I missing an obvious trick? I'm using C, as it happens, but could use Java; by no means an expert in either.

Comment: You can try to use a bitvector. Declare a variable as, lets say, unsigned short int, and consider each bit a different digit (e.g: digit 0 is bit 0, digit 1 is bit 1..etc) and later you can just see if the number is 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... to check if only one digit is on.

Comment: Nine unique numbers between 1 and 9 sum to 45; does that help?

Comment: @EricLippert probably not, as various other sets of 10 digits also sum to 45

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Good point. John Tortugo's suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C here is one way to do it:

```
// use an array, not a bunch of separate variables
int the_numbers[NUM_NUMBERS]; 

// here we assume you have filled in the numbers and validated
// that they are all in the range 0-9

bool duplicate_found = false;

bool seen[10] = { 0 };

for (int ii = 0; ii < NUM_NUMBERS; ++ii)
    if ( seen[ the_numbers[ii] ]++ )
    {
         duplicate_found = true;
         break;
    }
```

The postfix-`++` is a shortcut way of writing that we want to break out if it is already set; and we want to increment it if it is not already set (and we don't care if we also increment it when it was already set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a data structure that provides [set operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) - that makes a uniqueness test as easy as checking if the value already exists in the set.

In Java the [`Set` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and its implementation is the most generic way to achieve that effect, with [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) being the most efficient if uniqueness testing is all you need.

That said, if you only have a bunch of consecutive integers to test, then a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) may be a more suitable alternative. Alternatively, you might even code your own bit set using a simple array of boolean values:

```
boolean seen[] = new boolean[10];
...
// Mark digit 7 as seen
seen[7] = true;
...
// Test if digit 3 has been seen
if (seen[3]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just toss your numbers in a set and check if it allready contains the key. i.e.

```
@Test
public void nTest() throws Exception{
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(11);
    numbers.add(1111);

    Set<Integer> newNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    newNumbers.add(1);
    newNumbers.add(11);     
    newNumbers.add(111);

    //adds 111 to list  
    for(int a : newNumbers){
        if(!numbers.contains(a)){numbers.add(a);}
    }               
}
```